# Toolbar design breaks in a lollipop device

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have implemented a collapsible toolbar(prevented the collapse) for my app and it works fine Here is the Screenshot of my collapsible toolbar for a device of 4.2.2

[image]

When i execute my app in a device of 5.0, App looks like this,

[image]

as you can see there is a gap difference at the bottom of a status bar in 5.0, similarly when i go to other fragment activities of my app the app looks ugly in terms of UI here is what i mean

1. In a device 4.2.2

   [image]
2. In a device 5.0

   [image]

Here is the link for my styles [both styles folder](http://pastie.org/10919291)

I don't understand what is the mistake i have done. please help.

Thanks

Comment: We can't help you without code

Comment: I am not able to add the code, is it because of no of lines restriction?

Comment: I don't think lollipop reads the secondary, status bar color, if that's what you're referring to

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show your layout files?

Comment: post your style.xml file form both folder values-v21 and values

Comment: @ChiragSavsani as i am not able to post my code, here is the link for the styles http://pastie.org/10919291

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I had an issue similar to this, but the Toolbar content was pushed upwards. I added

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

to my app theme and it fixed it.

Comment: this fixes the issue for the toolbar height, but now the toolbar is overlapping the status bar here is how it looks now http://imgur.com/cPlb5jr

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution is solved. I fixed it by using `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` to the CoordinatorLayout and `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for the AppbarLayout and collapsingToolbar rather then using it in my style.xml.